# Awk sum up last n elements in for loop from csv file

Tags: bash, for-loop, ubuntu, variables, awk

I want to sum up the last `n` elements of a csv file that has only one row.

The expected `result` should be `110` see example csv file below.

Inside the awk function I casted the passed values from the bash script to int but it still fails.
The for loop should sum up each element, then the result should be assigned to the `sum` variable by the awk `print` statement

```
RWP="/foo/bar/rwp.csv"
DL=";"

function rrwpsh() {

    local n="${1}"
    
    local length=$(awk --field-separator=$DL '{ print NF; exit }' $RWP)
    local lower_bound=$[$length-$n]
    
    local sum=$(awk --field-separator=$DL -v lower_boundxxx=$lower_bound -v lengthxxx=$length 'BEGIN{lower_boundxxx_int=int(lower_boundxxx);lengthxxx_int=int(lengthxxx);for(j=lower_boundxxx_int;j<=lengthxxx_int;j++)x+=$j;print x}' $RWP)

    echo "sum: " $sum
}

let n=3 # example value
result=$(rrwpsh $n)
echo -e "result " $result
```

the csv file contains numbers

```
20;1;2;100;7;3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from stdin:

```
$ echo "20;1;2;100;7;3" | awk -F\; -v n=3 '{for(i=0;i<n;i++)s+=$(NF-i);print s}'
110
```

From file:

```
$ awk -F\; -v n=3 '{    # set delimiter and the n value
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    # looping from 0..(n-1)
        s+=$(NF-i)      # sum up related fields
    print s             # output
}' file
```